# Import urllib.request, ImportError: No module named request

Tags: python, importerror

I am trying to import urllib.request for python 2.7.10 on PyCharm 4.5.4 on Window 10 but getting the error "ImportError: No module named request".

Answer (score 49):

The urllib.request modules have been deprecated ..
just use

```
import urllib
```

And for your function if you were earlier writing say

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve
```

Now you just write

```
urllib.urlretrieve
```

Answer (score 21):

I have also faced the same error and Googled to solve it.
`urlib.request` is for Python 3.0.

You may use the code below:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlopen(url)
```

Answer (score 12):

You'll get this error if you try running a python 3 file with python 2.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this in Python3

```
try:
    x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/search?q=test')
    print(x.read())

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

It may happen sometimes, usually in the Linux environment. You have both 2.x and 3.x versions of python installed.

So, in that case, if you are using the command **python "file.py"**

then by default, it will python 2.x will run the file.

So, use the command **python3 "file.py"**

I was facing this issue. Maybe it can resolve someone's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib
response = urllib.urlopen("http://google.com")
html = response.read()
print(html)
```

The first line "#!/usr/bin/env python3" is important, as it let python know that this is Python 3 file, not 2.

Hope everything works.

Answer (score -2):

Use > `Path\easy_install.exe` requests if you have a windows machine, where `easy_install` can be found in your **Python*\Scripts** folder, if it was installed. (Note Path\easy_install.exe is an example, mine is C:\Python32\Scripts\easy_install.exe)

If you don't have easy install and are running on a windows machine, you can get it here: 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute

If you manually want to add a library to a windows machine, you can download the compressed library, uncompress it, and then place it into the Lib folder of your python path.

> OR

You need to install `pip` first and then install `django-request` using pip

```
pip install django-request
```

also install,

```
python setup.py install
```

then import

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

> Helpful Tips:to chech [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html)